# How to find the Joint Cumulative Distribution Function in this region?

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Find the Joint Cumulative Distribution Function of
>
> $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1 & 0 \le x \le 2, 0 \le y \le 1, 2y \le x \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

If i use the definition $F(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^y1\ dudv$ for any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

How i define the regions?

It's easy show that for the region $x<0, y<0$ then $F(x,y)=0$, but i have problems defining the other regions.

Comment: Please double check that $f$, it is not a valid probability density function.

Answer (score 1):

Please double check that $f$. It is not a valid probability density function, since it integrates to $1/4$.  Either the support or the function has an error.

Anyway, as it stands now, that support is $\{(x,y):0\leq 2y\leq x\leq 1\}$ which the triangle, $\triangle\langle0,0\rangle\langle1,0\rangle\langle1,1/2\rangle$.

So here are the obvious regions. Fill in the rest of the details once you've double checked $f$.

$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases}\int_0^y\int_0^x f(s,t)\mathrm d s~\mathrm d t &:&0\leq 2y<x<1 &\text{within the triangle}\\&:& &\text{right of the triangle}\\&:& &\text{above the triangle}\\ 1&:& 1/2\leq y\text{ and }1\leq x &\text{above }\textbf{and}\text{ right of the triangle }\\0&:&y< 0 \text{ or }x<0 &\text{below }\textbf{or}\text{ left of the triangle}   \end{cases}$$